# Scikit-learn - Working with data that the shape varies

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-structures, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of about 1k samples and I want to apply some unsuspervised techniques in order to clustering and visualization of these data.

The data can be interpreted as a table of a spreadsheet and unfortunately it doensn't have a very defined pattern of structure. The number of table lines varies, but not the columns.

The data is structured like this:

```
sample 1:

{
  "table1": {
    "column1": [
      "-",
      "-",
      "-"
    ],
    "column2": [
      "2017-04-16 10:00",
      "2017-04-16 10:00",
      "2017-04-16 10:00"
    ],
    "column3": [
      "-",
      "-",
      "-"
    ],
    "column4": [
      "name X",
      "name Y",
      "name Z"
    ],
    "column5": [
      "0",
      "0",
      "0"
    ],
  }
}


sample 2:

{
  "table1": {
    "column1": [
      "-",
      "-",
      "-",
      "-",
      "-",
      "-",
      "-",
      "-"
    ],
    "column2": [
      "2017-04-10 22:00",
      "2017-04-10 22:00",
      "2017-04-10 22:00",
      "2017-04-10 22:00",
      "2017-04-10 22:00",
      "2017-04-10 22:00",
      "2017-04-10 22:00",
      "2017-04-10 22:00"
    ],
    "column3": [
      "-",
      "-",
      "-",
      "-",
      "-",
      "-",
      "-",
      "-"
    ],
    "column4": [
      "name A",
      "name Z",
      "name B",
      "name X",
      "name C",
      "name D",
      "name E",
      "name F"
    ],
    "coumn5": [
      "",
      "",
      "3",
      "1",
      "0",
      "3",
      "0",
      "0"
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I work with these data for the unsupervised learning algorithms that scikit-learn offers? Is padding a way forward for this problem? If so, how can I apply the padding on this case?

Comment: Have you tried with `Imputer`? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation-of-missing-values

Comment: I don't think this can solve my problem because there're 'missing' rows, not columns.

Comment: It's the same, first, you can always transpose the table. Second, you can have rows with all NaN values.